# EJB cannot find Java class library

Tags: java, ejb, remote-access

Hello i tried to develop a EJB Application using Java class library project that contains a remote interface for the session bean. [I used this tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html)

When i try to run my EJB i get an exception saying

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Specified library jar Remote.jar does not exist : C:\Users\Lakshitha\Desktop\New%20Jobhunt\Remote\dist\Remote.jar

I checked the path in that folder and that jar file exist. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you dont have space and special character in path ,but it seems in your path `C:\Users\Lakshitha\Desktop\New%20Jobhunt\Remote\dist\Remote.jar`

in your case `New%20Jobhunt` which may be some special UTF-8 characters or spaces.so please create a new dir or path without space or special character and try to execute your application again.